# Accumulo: Equivalent of MongoDB createIndex()

Tags: accumulo

I am new to Accumulo and I am trying to retrieve all rowIDs corresponding to a column family/qualifier. In MongoDB, this could be done by creating an index on the field using createIndex(). IS there any way of doing the same in Accumulo?

Comment: I think the IndexingClient.java class can be used here but I am using Python (pyaccumulo). I don't think pyaccumulo has support for this.

Answer (score 0):

RowIds in Accumulo can be retrieved in you know the family or qualifier

**Code for Java**

```
Scanner scan = conn.createScanner("tableName", new Authorizations());
//for scanning on only Column Family
scan.fetchColumnFamily(new Text("CF"));
//for Scanning on both family and qualifier  
scan.fetchColumn(new Text("CF"),new Text("CQ"));
for (Entry<Key, Value> entry : scan) {
System.out.println(entry.getKey().getRow());
}
```

**Accumulo Shell**
  After selecting the specific table, use cammand

scan -c CF:CQ

Answer (score 0):

Extracting RowIds from Column Family and Qualifier can be done in the above mentioned way its recommended to make groups of family for better performance in this case.

And for searching on Values , I recomend you to make reverse Indexes